Info.plist entry for watch-only app on non-exempt encryption?
I am developing a watch only app, and want to get rid of confirming compliance to non-exempt encryption every time I upload a new build App Store Connect for testing.
With a regular iOS app, I can set the "App Uses Non-Exempt Encryption" key of the Info.plist file of the iOS target to 'No', and that handles this for me.
I am trying to do the same with my watch-only app, but it has no effect. I have tried adding it to both the WatchKit extension's and the watch app's 'Info.plist' respectively.
It is rejected by App Store Connect when uploading, if the key is added to the App target.
It is, however, accepted when the key is added to the WatchKit extension. I still need to explicitly confirm compliance in App Store Connect to make the app available for testing though, so it seem to have no effect.
I feel like I am missing something obvious. Any advice or thoughts?

Same problem here… did you find a fix?

No, nothing so far unfortunately.
